# Cannot add or update a child row SQL error

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, foreign-keys

I am trying to do the following transaction:

```
static async save(habit){
    await db.beginTransaction;
    try {
        await db.execute('SELECT @habitId:=MAX(habits.habitId)+1 FROM habits');
        await db.execute('INSERT INTO habits(habits.habitId, habits.name, habits.repeatVal, habits.notification, habits.color, habits.question, habits.id) VALUES (@habitId, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [habit.name, habit.repeatVal, habit.notification, habit.color, habit.question, habit.id]);
        await db.execute('INSERT INTO habit_status(habit_status.habitId, habit_status.date, habit_status.status) VALUES (@habitId, "2021-04-01", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-02", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-03", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-04", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-05", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-06", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-07", 0), (@habitId, "2021-04-08", 0)');
        await db.commit();

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error occurred while creating habit: ${err.message}`, err);
        db.rollback(function(){});
        console.info('Rollback successful');
        return 'error creating habit';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

> Error occurred while creating habit: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`intend`.`habit_status`, CONSTRAINT `habit` FOREIGN KEY (`habitId`) REFERENCES `habits` (`habitId`) ON DELETE CASCADE) Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`intend`.`habit_status`, CONSTRAINT `habit` FOREIGN KEY (`habitId`) REFERENCES `habits` (`habitId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

As well as:

```
TypeError: db.rollback is not a function
```

I think it's because @habitId is probably not passing the habitId to my third execute function. But why? And how to fix this?

Comment: as ylong as you are in a transaction and have not comitted the insert the @habit is not in the database, ergo you can't make this in a tansaction

Comment: But if I use a transaction to do the same thing in phpmyadmin for example it works.

Comment: this would only work when the transation is in the same execute, you have to chekc f you can  do multi queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you didn't call `beginTransaction` properly forgetting to add brackets:

```
await db.beginTransaction();
```

As of `db.rollback` try to check if `db` is really a DB connection object you expect it to be.

Comment: That's correct. I have fixed that by now. Unfortunately the transaction still fails with the SQL-Message " 'Malformed communication packet.'"

Comment: That's not the error you indicated in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Can we issue await db.commit(); after first INSERT statement.